Animated series with female main character named Mimi when broadcast in Greece
There was a cartoon I used to watch around 90's (somewhere between 1995-2005, I just remember I was a kid when it was on TV)
In Greek television, the girl's name that was the main character was Mimi.
Her hair (and probably other people's too, as I recall) was white and fuzzy. The haircuts were actually quite similar to the haircuts on Dilbert comic
Dilbert haircuts here
The episodes had some weird content like dream scenarios or time travel, but I do not quite remember.
The opening song had lyrics translated in greek that were somewhat like
"Hello Mimi, let's see what life is all about. Hello Mimi, all your friends are together"
For some reason, I had a feeling this series was French but I cannot find it anywhere.

The series is called Mimi and Mr Bobo. In Greek: Η Μιμη και η παρεα της .
IMDb Storyline:

Who would've guessed it! They're just a gang of neighborhood kids but they can turn the town upside down in a blink of the eyes. Shopkeepers, mobsters, rock stars and other characters - no-one can escape the Machiavellian adventures of Mimi and her friends.





Oh my, thank you so much! This is the series I was looking for. I wasn't even expecting an answer anymore. I'll text my sister right away! :)

@cindy Please let me know if these edits were incorrect. I just added them to make them more in line with what is expected here.

The edit is correct, however, the answer is just right and definitely no less than is expected.
Yet there is one thing that bothers me. I upvoted the answer and it had 0 voted, which means someone downvoted the correct answer. What is wrong with people

@dimokratis john, I'm glad I helped :) unfortunately, I cannot answer to comments (it says that i need 50 reputations?) so I used this, please remove it if it goes against the rules

@CynthiaFrost Are you and cindy the same user? If yes then you should go for account merge.

Is it What about mimi?.  But Mimi was not a white haired girl but a red headed girl. 
From Wikipedia page of this TV show, 

What About Mimi? is a Canadian animated series. The main character is Mimi Mortin, a clever, red-headed girl in the sixth grade who lives in the town of Starfish Bay. The series was produced by Decode Entertainment and Studio B Productions and co-directed by Josh Mepham and Colleen Holub, and won the Pulcinella Award for the Best Series for Children in 2001.

You can watch the intro theme song of this show here. The IMDb page of this show doesn't say that it is translated into Greek. But there is a chance it might get translated into that language. (What about mimi greek is a popular search on youtube.) There are some episodes available on Youtube.   

No, this is not what I am looking for
I found "What about Mimi" while searching and for a moment I thought I had it. Definitely not what I am looking for
